# How to use Alarm Manger Class for notifcation about an event on specific date and time?

Tags: android-studio, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm quite new to Android Development. I'm working on a project "Anniversary Reminder" so far I've managed to get data from user, Name & Event Date (MMMM dd) only month and day from DatePickerDialog. Now I have no idea... how do I implement notifying the user about the event using AlarmManager?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the data now, next thing is set an alarm at a particular time from your **Activity**

```
 AlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);
 mAlarmManager.set(int type, 
            long triggerAtMillis, 
            long intervalMillis, 
            PendingIntent operation);
```

check out [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for more information.

Then define the Notification you want to trigger in the **Receiver** class when alarm is hit .

refer this link
[schedule notifications using AlarmManager](http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/)